# ios table sections and rows all locked to top of table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

My ios table has started bugging out and I'm stumped.  All the sections and rows in the table are locking to the very top of the table view.  This only seems to happen on my device (have tested on a few - we all have latest ios 7).  I've reinstalled the app a few times but the problem remains for me.

I'm using a modified version of this bubble chat:  http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/

Here is a screenshot that shows the problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2hwbxe2923q3wp/IMG_0598.jpg

Each message is a table section with 2 rows - one for the header (the white text) and one for the speech bubble.

I can post more code if required, but can anyone tell me how an ios table view could be broken like this?

UPDATE:  App was just rejected by apple because the same issue happened for them as well, using an iPad Air.  I am wondering if this is a bug specific to the Air because it doesn't happen on other devices running the same iOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  The return data type on tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath was set to float - should have been CGFloat.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you change something and it only affects fresh installs or only works on existing installs, including layouts. You could test on a fresh simulator that has been reset prior to running on it. You could also install it on an existing device on a different name so it will be a new app with new settings, a different install directory and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Found the issue but I'll remember this for next time.